# how use OAuth 2.0 from google for post blogger api?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, blogger

when requesting post for blogger api like

`https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogid/posts?key=my key`

Authorization: /* OAuth 2.0 token here */ required

How get and use this token and I get josn client_id and client_secret?

body josn is

```
{
  "kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "title": "A new post",
  "content": "content..."
}
```